# tangents parametric equation

Tags: calculus

$\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
  x(t)=t^2 +1 \\
y(t)= t^3 -1
\end{array}
\right.$

i) show for every t_0 not 0 that the given curve got a tangent line at $(x(t_0)),y(t_0))$ and find a parametric representation of this tangent.

ii) Find the intersection between the two tangents $((x(-1)),(y(-1))$ and $((x(1)),(y(1))$

so on the first one Im pretty much clueless, but I think I shoulld get a tangent on the form

$x=f(t_0) + f'(t_0)(t-t_0)$

$y=g(t_0) + g'(t_0)(t-t_0)$

on ii) I'm trying to find the tangent at $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ is that correct? well I get $dy/dx = 3t/2$ and now im stuck trying to find the t values for the coordinate $(-1,-1)$ can I just find the t value using any of the equations? if I use $x(t)$ I get $t^2 = -2$ ? and $y(t)= t^3 =0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i) Tangent=$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{3t^2}{2t}=\frac{3t}{2}, t\neq 0$. This means that any $t$ but $t\neq 0$, you have tanget line. When $t=t_0$, tangent is $\frac{3t_0}{2}$, which may be the parametric representation.

ii) $$m=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3t}{2}$$
When $$t=-1\rightarrow m=-3/2 ~ \& ~(x,y)=(2,-2)\rightarrow y=\frac{-3}{2}(x-2)-2$$
When $$t=1\rightarrow m=3/2 ~ \& ~ (x,y)=(2,0)\rightarrow y=\frac{3}{2}(x-2)$$
Now solve these two equations: $\left(x= \frac{4}{3},y= -1\right)$

Please double check the numerical analysis !!!

Comment: $(x(-1),y(-1))$ means that $x$ and $y$ points are evaluated at $t=-1$, then you can just substitute $t=-1$ to that original set of equations with $t$.

Comment: yes, exactly !!!

Comment: Pls check edited version :)